# unable to create multiple NotificationCompat.Builders

Tags: android, push-notification

In our android app, we are trying to send different two types of notifications, one that stays for a longer time and uses .setFullScreenIntent parameter and one that is without setFullscreenIntent. So we created two notification compat builder vide code as given hereunder:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, MainActivity.asw_fcm_channel)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .setTimeoutAfter(60000)
                    .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_CALL)
                    .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .addAction(action)
                    .addAction(action1)
                    .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                    .setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent2, true)
                    .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder1 = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, MainActivity.asw_fcm_channel)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setTimeoutAfter(60000)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_CALL)
                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .addAction(action)
                .addAction(action1)
                .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
```

And now in Firebase messaging post process that is used to send the notification, we have a parameter called "tag".

```
$fcmUrl = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

 $token=$to;

     $data = [
            'title' =>$title,
            'body' =>$msg,
            'image'=>'https://mbracecloud.com/appln_enterprise/images_user/file_2022_37_46_2372744327498576956.jpg',
            'uri'=>"",
            'tag'=>'View Message'
            ];
```

Now based on that parameter, we tried to use tag:"View Message" as an "if" to use notificationBuilder template and tag:"Start" for using notificationBuilder1 template as specified above. But its just not working

```
if (tag=="View Message") {
                Notification noti = notificationBuilder.build();
                noti.flags = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                notificationManager.notify(notification_id, notificationBuilder.build());
            }

        if (tag=="Start") {
            Notification noti = notificationBuilder1.build();
            noti.flags = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            notificationManager.notify(notification_id, notificationBuilder1.build());
        }
```

Shall appreciate should you guide us as how to do this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832

Comment: Ok got it, how do i use that as .equal as if statement

Comment: `if (tag.equals("View Message"))`